# Do I have to subclass in this case?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uiresponder

I have a UIViewController and a UITextView in it. I want to get touchesbegan method in UIViewController, but of course, it's being blocked b the UITextView. So, do I have to subclass UITextView to override resignsfirstresponder? There's got be antoher way, otherwise I am going to have to create two files just to override a method that simply returns NO.

Thanks.

Update: Basically I want to display a UIActionSheet whenever the user taps on the screen. But I also want the UITextView to be scrollable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set your `UITextView.userInteractionEnabled = NO` (this can be done in interface builder/Xcode 4). Then touches will pass through to the view behind your UITextView. You could use a UIControl instead of a UIView for your view controller's view if you want to intercept touches to your view controller's view.

Can you tell us more about the interaction you're trying to create?

Comment: Thanks for our reply. I'll try the user interactionenabled solution you provided. Also, i'll update my question with more info. Thanks again.

Comment: That's still not passing the touch to the view controller.

Comment: the touches will be passed to the view controller's view, not the view controller itself.

Comment: (but disabling user interaction will make your uitextview non-scrollable.) sounds like you may have to overlay a view on the entire screen to intercept all touches, then pass those touches through to the views behind your overlay view.

Comment: you can override `-touchesBegan:withEvent:` `touchesEnded:withEvent:`, `touchesMoved:withEvent:` and `touchesCanceled:withEvent:` in your overlay view to do this.